# How to parse utc date

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I Parse Date like

> Sat Aug22 14.00:00 UTC +200 2009

I tried using

> DateTime.ParseExact("Sat Aug 22 14.00:00 UTC +200 2009", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTC yyyy", null);

Comment: You don't account for the +200

Comment: What format can be used to account for +200

Comment: I don't know C#, but I figured you'd be able to look it up if you pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: What did you try? is the input a string?

Comment: @Davis that is the input string, The error I get is String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Are you sure the offset is specified correctly? +200 ? Usually its specified in hours +2 or +2:00.

Comment: The input string contains a '.' for the hour separator, yet in the DateTime.ParseExact call you use a ':'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it works. After 14, you have "." - change it to ":"

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Sat Aug 22 14:00:00 UTC+0200 2009", 
                    "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss UTCzzzz yyyy", null);
```

[Reference](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/386195-cast-string-thu-jul-21-00-00-00-utc-0100-200-type-dateis-not-valid-system-invalidcastexception)